# Update multiple values with button_to - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I'm having trouble updating columns in my table with a button in Rails.
I've looked around stackoverflow for answers, but can't seem to get anything working...

In my app, I want users to be able to "rent" and "return" pins.
When they click the "Rent" button, I want it to change the pin's columns.

Example: rented: => true, renter_id: 1"

In my Pins controller:

```
def rent
@pin = Pin.update_attribute(:renter_id => @user.id)
end
```

In my View:

```
<%= button_to "Rent Now!", {:controller => "pins", :action => "rent", :renter_id => @user.id }, :class => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block'%>
```

Schema:

```
create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.string   "link"
t.boolean  "rented"
t.integer  "renter_id"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that `update_attribute` is an instance method. But you are trying to call it as a class method on `Pin`.  Perhaps do a controller like so.

```
def rent
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  if @pin.update_attributes(renter_id: @user.id)
    #handle success
  else
    #handle failure
  end
end
```

Also make sure that your routes are properly set up as a post request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. Now Im running into an error "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Pin without an ID):"

Comment: the params that are being passed do not have an id.  Check your `rake routes` to find our what id you are updating pin by.

Comment: Im confused. Haha. That is my update route, what can I do with it?

Comment: what about your rent route?

Comment: I like to just do this: `= link_to "Rent_Now", rent_pin_path(@pin), method: :post`  etc...  you need to pass the id to the parameters so that it can recognize the object's corresponding row.

Comment: pins_rent POST   /pins/rent(.:format)           pins#rent

Comment: So I should use link_to instead of button_to ?

Comment: `def rent
    @user = current_user
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    if @pin.update_attributes(renter_id: @user.id, rented: true)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Rental was made.'
    else
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Rental failed.'
    end
  end`

Answer (score 2):

[update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) takes 2 arguments, the attribute and the value

So it should be like this

```
update_attribute(:renter_id, @user.id)
```

If you want to update multiple attributes at once or if you want validations to be triggered, use `update_attributes`

```
update_attributes(:attr1 => value1, :attr2 => value2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I changed my controller code but it didnt work. `def rent
    @user = current_user
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    @rent = Pin.update_attribute(:renter_id, @user.id)
  end`  The error says "Couldn't find Pin without an ID"